# Remotely identify Wyse terminal models across the network

Tags: networking, citrix

We currently have a large number of Wyse terminals in our estate that are used to log in to our Citrix XenApp 4.5 solution. The Wyse terminals are a mix of older S10 models and new T10 terminals. Ou challenge is to identify how many S10 devices are in the estate of Wyse terminals. As a result I was wondering if anyone knew if there was a way to identify these upon log in using the PNAgent and the config.xml? If not does anyone know how we might identify remotely how many we have by any other means?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is nmap an option? Does the output of nmap -O for two hosts known to be S10 and T10 respectively show a different result?

Comment: Thanks for the comment but no I have tried nmap and is returns an unknown TCP/IP figureprint.

Comment: what I meant is: do the fingerprints differ between the two? If so, you should be able to tell them apart by that difference - http://nmap.org/book/osdetect-unidentified.html

Answer (score 0):

Get them to report in your [Wyse Device Manager](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/wyse-wdm/pd).

The workgroup edition is free.

WBM should allow you to scan for the clients. And then tell you the device type.

Also: the Citrix console can tell you the ICA client version for each active session. And embedded  systems tend to show a weird version code. You might be able to tell them apart that way, too.